# Bind ctrl + u keystroke in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeyup

I am trying to build a *hotkey* into my web application in *jQuery*. I am trying to bind the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> key stroke. Here is what I have:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.which == 117) {
      if($("#nav-user-details").length > 0) {
        $("#nav-user-details").find(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
      }
    }
});
```

This is not working though. How do I bind this key strokes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this please** http://jsfiddle.net/TN7GZ/

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and the screen will alert.

This will fit your need `:)`

**Code**

```
var isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup=function(e){
    if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=false;
}
document.onkeydown=function(e){
    if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
    if(e.which == 85 && isCtrl == true) {
        //run code for CTRL+U -- ie, whatever!
        alert('CTRL + U stuff');
        return false;
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

I’m pretty sure `85` is the keycode for `u`, or am I missing something?

If you want mac support as well (the command key), it can get messy. I wrote a snippet before that might help you, but it involves browser detections (yuck):

```
var cmd = false;

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {

    if(detectMacCommand(e.which)) {
        cmd = true;
        return;
    }

    // now detect print (ctr/cmd + p)
    if ( e.which == 85 && ( e.ctrl || cmd ) ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('ctrl/cmd + u');
    }

}).on('keyup', function(e) {

    if(detectMacCommand(e.which)) {
        cmd = false;
        return;
    }

});

function detectMacCommand(key) {
    return ( $.browser.mozilla && key == 224 ||
             $.browser.opera   && key == 17 ||
             $.browser.webkit  && ( key == 91 || key == 93 ));
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/afijam/2

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use keydown instead of keypress. Keypress does not trigger for non-char keys.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.which === 81) {
    alert("key pressed");
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: So this does not work, `e.which` is always just the value of `ctrl`.

Comment: I've tried it in chrome. It works there.
Editing with the exact code I used.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keypress("u",function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey)
    alert("Ctrl+U was pressed!!");
});
```

Comment: So this works, but only if they pressing `ctrl` first, then `u`. Is there a way to make it work either way?

Comment: This still alerts when you press ctrl + *any key*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var prevKey = null;
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
  var thisKey = e.which;

  if (prevKey && prevKey == 17) {
    if (thisKey == 85) {
      // Your code.
    }
  }

  prevKey = thisKey;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a `Xhtml` file and you get an error `The entity must immediately follow the &` then you should use `&&amp;&amp;` instead of `&&`.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.